# Taking a screenshot using c# with out including task bar.

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

How to take screenshot using c# with out including task bar.I tried some codes but it takes whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` it gives you the screen excluding task bar

```
Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width,
                           Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height,
                           PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);


gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.X,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Y,
                            0,
                            0,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size,
                            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

bmpScreenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

**[Screen.WorkingArea Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

> Gets the working area of the display. The working area is the desktop
>   area of the display, excluding taskbars, docked windows, and docked
>   tool bars.