# How to access Clipboard from System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to capture a screenshot from my application and set it as the `picturebox.Image` when a certain condition is true at a certain point of time. This condition has to be checked repeatedly.
For checking this condition, I am using a `System.Timers.Timer`. But `Clipboard.GetImage()` isn't working.

I have tried the following code, but that's not working.

```
timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 10000; //I'm checking the condition every 10 second or so
timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

```
void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
            if(myCondition==true)
               GetScreenshot();
}
```

```
void GetScreenshot()
{
            try
            {
                SendKeys.SendWait("{PRTSC}");
                Thread.Sleep(500);

                var image = Clipboard.GetImage();

                pictureBox1.Image = image;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
}
```

This doesn't work and if i try to save the image then it gives `Object reference not set` kind of exception.

I've read somewhere that it happens due to the timer being MTA , so it can't get access to clipboard. I have tried using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, but that slows the program down due to the continuous check I guess.

Is there any simple way I can get it to work without slowing down the performance.
I'm quite new to C#, so a little description of how a certain solution works will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you try to take the screenshot in code instead of sending keys somewhere?

Comment: While what you're doing doesn't sound wrong, a similar result can be achieved quite nicely using code like from here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Saving-a-screenshot-using-C-6883abb3

Comment: It sounds like you only need to capture the screenshot when `myCondition == true`. Have you considered making `myCondition` into a property, and then calling `GetScreenshot()` from there (in the setter, and only when `value == true`)?

Answer (score 0):

`Clipboard.GetImage` returns an image which is stored in the clipboard.
Clipboard is somewhat complicated storage; with a possibility of simultaneous staroge of different types of different datas, and should be discussed as a whole new topic.

But, you mentioned you want a screenshot of your screen. Clipboard itself doesn't have functionality of capturing your screen, unless a specific software takes the screenshot and puts it into the clipboard. For instance <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> button does jsutjust that.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655192/taking-a-screenshot-using-c-sharp-with-out-including-task-bar) however, may be of help, if you want to capture the screen yourself:

```
Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width,
                       Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height,
                       PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);


gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.X,
                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Y,
                        0,
                        0,
                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size,
                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

bmpScreenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Instead of copying code from another post, please vote to close as a duplicate of the other post instead.

Comment: @RufusL along with the copied code I have provided some explanation, which other posts lack. Without it, OP might have had wrong grasp on these things.

Comment: Yeah, but was the additional information that "Clipboard is complicated" really an answer? The OP's code works absolutely fine on my machine after switching from a `System.Timers.Timer` to a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.